# Python: Pycharm runtimes

Tags: python, performance

I am witnessing some strange run time issues with PyCharm that are explained below. The code has been run on a machine with 20 cores and 256 GB RAM and there is sufficient memory to spare. I am not showing any of the real functions as it is a reasonably large project, but am more than happy to add details upon request.

In short, I have a `.py` file project with the following structure:

```
import ...
import ...

cpu_cores = control_parameters.cpu_cores
prng = RandomState(123)

def collect_results(result_list):
    return pd.DataFrame({'start_time': result_list[0::4],
                  'arrival_time': result_list[1::4],
                  'tour_id': result_list[2::4],
                  'trip_id': result_list[3::4]})

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Run the serial code
    st = starttimes.StartTimesCreate(prng)
    temp_df, two_trips_df, time_dist_arr = st.run()

     # Prepare the dataframe to sample start times. Create groups from the input dataframe
    temp_df1 = st.prepare_two_trips_more_df(temp_df, two_trips_df)
    validation.logger.info("Dataframe prepared for multiprocessing")

    grp_list = []
    for name, group in temp_df1.groupby('tour_id'):  ### problem lies here in runtimes
        grp_list.append(group)
    validation.logger.info("All groups have been prepared for multiprocessing, "
                           "for a total of %s groups" %len(grp_list))

################ PARALLEL CODE BELOW #################
```

The **for loop** is run on a dataframe of 10.5million rows and 18 columns. In the current form it takes about **25 mins** to create the list of groups (2.8M groups). These groups are created and then fed to a multiprocess pool, code for which is not shown.

The 25 mins it is taking is quite long for I have done the following test run as well, which takes only **7 mins**. Essentially, I saved the *temp_df1* file to a CSV and then just batched in the pre-saved file and run the same **for loop** as before.

```
import ...
import ...

cpu_cores = control_parameters.cpu_cores
prng = RandomState(123)

def collect_results(result_list):
    return pd.DataFrame({'start_time': result_list[0::4],
                  'arrival_time': result_list[1::4],
                  'tour_id': result_list[2::4],
                  'trip_id': result_list[3::4]})

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Run the serial code
    st = starttimes.StartTimesCreate(prng)

    temp_df1 = pd.read_csv(r"c:\\...\\temp_df1.csv")
    time_dist = pd.read_csv(r"c:\\...\\start_time_distribution_treso_1.csv")
    time_dist_arr = np.array(time_dist.to_records())

    grp_list = []
    for name, group in temp_df1.groupby('tour_id'):
        grp_list.append(group)
    validation.logger.info("All groups have been prepared for multiprocessing, "
                           "for a total of %s groups" %len(grp_list))
```

**QUESTION**
So, what is it that is causing the code to run 3 times faster when I just batch in the file versus when the file is created as part of a function further upstream?

Thanks in advance and please let me know how I can further clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question as I stumbled upon the answer while doing a bunch of tests and thankfully when I googled the solution someone else had the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042952/pandas-dataframe-aggregate-on-column-whos-dtype-category-leads-to-slow-perf/51164942#51164942). The explanation for why having categorical columns is a bad idea when doing group_by operations can be found at the above link. Thus I am not going to post it here. Thanks.